# Excel style autofill using python

Tags: python

I have an Excel file with subtotals and groupings like

```
Region  |Country      |State
--------|-------------|-----
Americas|United States| AA
        |             | AE
        |             | AK
        |Canada       | AB
        |             | BC
Europe  |France       | A1
        |             | A2
        |             | A3
```

and I want to fill each blank cell so it can be loaded to a datatable - sort of like a spreadsheets AutoFill feature so that the output in CSV looks like

```
Region  ,Country       ,State
Americas,United States ,AA
Americas,United States ,AE
Americas,Canada        ,AB
Americas,Canada        ,BC
...
```

I am using the following code, but am thinking there is likely a better way to do this

```
csv_file = open(opFile, 'w')
with open(fname) as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=','):
        for curCol, col in enumerate(row):
            colText = "".join(map(str,col)).strip('"').strip()  
            if curCol in autoFillCols:
                if colText == "":
                    colText = lastValues[curCol]
                else:
                    lastValues[curCol] = colText
            csv_file.write('"' + colText + '",')
        csv_file.write('\n')
csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the String package (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). It has functions:

```
string.ljust(s, width[, fillchar])
string.rjust(s, width[, fillchar])
string.center(s, width[, fillchar])
```

In practice, these can be as simple as:

```
"Welcome to WonderApp".center(74)
```

Comment: That is for single strings, whereas I am trying to essentially pad a table